# Can I add secondary gpu to baremetal server

Tags: gpu, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, cloud-bare-metal

Can I add secondary or another GPU to bare metal server,

I tried to get the price details to confirm the same but getting following error

```
slcli order place --verify  --billing monthly --complex-type SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Hardware_Server DUAL_E52600_V4_12_DRIVES DALLAS12 REBOOT_KVM_OVER_IP UNLIMITED_SSL_VPN_USERS_1_PPTP_VPN_USER_PER_ACCOUNT NESSUS_VULNERABILITY_ASSESSMENT_REPORTING NOTIFICATION_EMAIL_AND_TICKET 1_IP_ADDRESS AUTOMATED_NOTIFICATION MONITORING_HOST_PING BANDWIDTH_500_GB REDUNDANT_POWER_SUPPLY INTEL_TXT_TRUSTED_EXECUTION_TECHNOLOGY OS_UBUNTU_16_04_LTS_XENIAL_XERUS_MINIMAL_64_BIT INTEL_INTEL_XEON_E52620_V4_2_10 RAM_128_GB_DDR4_2133_ECC_REG 10_GBPS_REDUNDANT_PUBLIC_PRIVATE_NETWORK_UPLINKS DISK_CONTROLLER_NONRAID HARD_DRIVE_1_9TB_SSD_SED_5DWPD HARD_DRIVE_2_00_TB_SATA_2  HARD_DRIVE_3_8TB_SSD_SED_3DWPD GPU_NVIDIA_TESLA_K80 GPU_NVIDIA_TESLA_M10_ACCELERATOR
SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Public): Unable to add NVIDIA Tesla M10 GPU Accelerator  because a Graphics Processing Unit price has already been added.



slcli order place --verify  --billing monthly --complex-type SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Hardware_Server DUAL_E52600_V4_12_DRIVES DALLAS12 REBOOT_KVM_OVER_IP UNLIMITED_SSL_VPN_USERS_1_PPTP_VPN_USER_PER_ACCOUNT NESSUS_VULNERABILITY_ASSESSMENT_REPORTING NOTIFICATION_EMAIL_AND_TICKET 1_IP_ADDRESS AUTOMATED_NOTIFICATION MONITORING_HOST_PING BANDWIDTH_500_GB REDUNDANT_POWER_SUPPLY INTEL_TXT_TRUSTED_EXECUTION_TECHNOLOGY OS_UBUNTU_16_04_LTS_XENIAL_XERUS_MINIMAL_64_BIT INTEL_INTEL_XEON_E52620_V4_2_10 RAM_128_GB_DDR4_2133_ECC_REG 10_GBPS_REDUNDANT_PUBLIC_PRIVATE_NETWORK_UPLINKS DISK_CONTROLLER_NONRAID HARD_DRIVE_1_9TB_SSD_SED_5DWPD HARD_DRIVE_2_00_TB_SATA_2  HARD_DRIVE_3_8TB_SSD_SED_3DWPD GPU_NVIDIA_TESLA_K80 GPU_NVIDIA_TESLA_V100
SoftLayerAPIError(SoftLayer_Exception_Order_Item_Rule): The V100 can only be used with a V100
```

Comment: Looks like the API doesn't support an extra GPU, as the error rightly points out you already have one `Unable to add NVIDIA Tesla M10 GPU Accelerator  because a Graphics Processing Unit price has already been added.`

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible to order a baremetal servers with two GPU items through the SLCLI client.

It seems that there are issues in the slcli, it list only gpu0 items but there should be gpu0 and gpu1. The following issues were opened: [#983](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-python/issues/983), [#984](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-python/issues/984), and [#985](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-python/issues/985)

In the mean time, the only way is placing the order manually through the [placeOrder](https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/placeOrder/) method, use [verifyOrder](https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder/) if you are not ready to order, following have examples about how to order a baremetal, you need to change the values with your own and set the prices:

https://softlayer.github.io/rest/place_order/ (CURL or REST)

[Adding SSH keys to Softlayer JSON order for Bare metal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40429959/adding-ssh-keys-to-softlayer-json-order-for-bare-metal) (Python)

[Subnet error while ordering baremetal server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40578689/subnet-error-while-ordering-baremetal-server)

To order a DUAL_E52600_V4_12_DRIVES  you need to use the **packageId 553** and to know which item prices you need to send during the order you can use the following REST call:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package/553/getItemPrices?objectMask=mask[categories,pricingLocationGroup[locations]]
```

For DALLAS12 search for those items prices which have **locationGroupId = null**.

Comment: I tried with REST call but it seems very hard to get it, here is my one price list  `{"id": 208599},
                {"id": 175719},
                {"id": 176961},
                {"id": 198933},
                {"id": 35310},
                {"id": 99325},
                {"id": 25014},
                {"id": 34807},
                {"id": 50263},
                {"id": 83815},
                {"id": 33483},
                {"id": 34996},
                {"id": 32500},
                {"id": 80265},
                {"id": 141949},
                {"id": 165771}` in 553 package

Comment: but still I am getting following error `{"error":"20000 GB Bandwidth cannot be ordered with item 10 Gbps Redundant Private Network Uplinks. 10 Gbps Redundant Private Network Uplinks cannot be ordered with item 20000 GB Bandwidth. NVIDIA Tesla V100 Graphic Card cannot be ordered with location London 2.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Order_Item_Rule"}`   although `208599` is available in lon02

Comment: the item price 208599 has location conflicts, use `mask[categories,pricingLocationGroup[locations],item[description,locationConflicts]]` to retrieve the prices and their location conflicts. The location "London 2" has id 358694, and this id is in conflict with the price you selected, the resourceTableId=358694 in the list of conflicts means that 208599 cannot be ordered in the location 358694 (london 2).

Comment: I recommend to compare with the portal page and select another GPU if needed. The error about bandwidth is because you selected a public bandwidth and a  private uplink. For public bandwidth you need to select a "public & private" uplink or select a private bandwidth with a private uplink.

Comment: You can also try by using generic prices, the generic prices have `locationGroupId = null`